# How to connect Azure Data Studio inside a Docker container to SQL Server inside other container?

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker

In majority of the cases I'm able to connect to SQL Server (in a container) using

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 172.17.0.3 -U SA -P '<your password>'
```

IP address 172.17.0.3 being the ip of the container instance as provided by the docker network.  [As instructed by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) and combined with [Chuen Hing Lee's post here](https://chlee.co/how-to-install-and-host-sql-server-on-linux-with-docker-for-10-dollars-a-month/).

What if the Azure Data Studio (AzDS) is inside a container as well?
(mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest)

How to connect AzDS in container to the SQL Server in other container?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand. AzDS is a GUI application, and as such, cannot run in a container. But you should be able run AzDS on a host and connect to SQL Server running in the container.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm reasonably certain that Azure Data Studio for Linux is a Gnome+X11 based program. I'm sure some enterprising person could figure out how to install and run it in a docker container, connecting to an X11 display server on some other GUI-based computer (or maybe even the host) ... seems like a lot of trouble to go to, though.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I believe ADS is an [Electron App](https://www.electronjs.org/) (based on VS code), not Gnome+X11.

Comment: @DanGuzman I did make a container with AzDS working; got the GUI indeed visible on the host machine. Just not getting the right network settings in place in the containerized AzDS instance or the SQL Server container instance. 

Any suggestions on the networking? IP config and ping from + to both containers to each other works. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @MOR, from the same container, you can connect successfully using `sqlcmd` but not `ADS`? If you can ping the container, verify port connectivity as well using `telnet`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks, but did not work. 'telnet' and 'nmap' show active service on port '1433' of MS SQL server container. See [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ILsljJe) .

What did work. The Azure Data Studio container is able to connect to the MS SQL server using '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 172.17.0.3 -U sa -P <your password>' (even with user 'sa' in lower caps). Any ideas on the AzDS perhaps? Thanks a lot for the time spent!